# How to send extra parameters on a link/button_to_remote call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, prototypejs

Prototype's Ajax accepts a parameter called 'parameters' with an hash array for parameters ([prototype doc](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/options)) which would automatically be sent as GET or POST vars, but I could not find how to add items to that array using the Rails button_to_remote method.

I could just add the parameters to the URL sent to the method, but that feels hackish.. Is there a better solution out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually found the solution! You can pass parameters in the function using the :with option, like this:

```
<%=button_to_remote "+3", {:url =>task_path(@project, @story, task), :with=>"'actual=3'"}%>
```

The trick is that the value for :with is a javascript expression that should return a key-value pair in the URL format, like "key=value". That's why there's extra quotes around the value on the same above.

A function could also be used to pull the information from the page, if necessary:

```
:with=>"getValuesForPostbackFunction()"
```

The function will be evaluated before the form is submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Using `button_to_remote` the only way to send parameters to the next action is putting them into the URI.

`button_to_remote` is intended as a functional equivalent of `link_to_remote`, which also has no other way of adding parameters.

If you need more fine-grained control, you need to build the full form and submit that to your action.

Comment: I actually found a way of passing extra parameters, check out my answer on my question!

Answer (score 0):

Add hidden input fields in the form that you're calling the button_to_remote on.

```
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="myValue">
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but there's no way to add an input tag in the form, because there's no form. button_to_remote creates a prototype Ajax object, without a form.